# Detecting Post type in Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin with the following code.

I'm trying to detect whether the page being viewed is a Page or a Post.  Depending on the value, I will choose to redirect the user to another page or not.

But currently I'm just getting no value at all.

```
 global $post;
 $da_post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

 echo "<!-- The post type is : $da_post_type -->" ;
```

Comment: Where is this code happening? What hook? Only this fragment is not enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I don't think this is in a Hook.  This code is straight from the Plugins main file.

Comment: Well, as you saw a hookless code don't bode well in a plugin ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i was having is that the code wasn't in a hook but just in the main plugin files.

So word press did know what the page id was.

I solved this with the following code:

```
function da_get_post_id()
{ 
  global $post;
  $da_post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

  echo "<!-- The post type is : $da_post_type -->" ;
}
add_action('wp','da_get_post_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `is_page($id)` ([Doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)). If it's not a page it's a post.

Comment: I think the problem i'm having is i can't detect the page ID.

Comment: You don't need to. using `is_page()` will show if your current page is a "page" or "post".

Answer (score 0):

simply add the code in the place where you want the checking

```
    global $post;

    if(is_page($post->ID))
      {
        ///write code for the pages
      }
    else
      {
        ///write code for the posts
      }
```